# What's the difference between 'eval $command' and $command?

Tags: bash, eval

What's the difference between:

```
eval echo lala
```

and:

```
command="echo lala"
$command
```

They both seem to have the same effect but I might be missing something. Also, if they **do** have the same effect, what's the point of `eval` command?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
y='FOO=hello; echo $FOO'
eval $y
```

It prints `hello`.

But this:

```
$y
```

says:

> -bash: FOO=hello;: command not found

So when you say `eval $y` it is just as if you had typed the content of `$y` into the interpreter.  But when you just say `$y` it needs to be a command that can be run, rather than some other tokens that the interpreter needs to parse (in the above example, a variable assignment).

If you know that a variable contains an executable command you can run it without `eval`.  But if the variable might contain Bash code which is not simply an executable command (i.e. something you could imagine passing to the C function `exec()`), you need `eval`.

Comment: I would say that a single command is _actual Bash code_, so maybe there's a better way to describe what you mean (although I'm not sure exactly how I'd word it, which is why I gave up on my answer!)

Comment: @TomFenech: That was indeed awkward phrasing.  I've replaced it.

Answer (score 4):

To expand on @JohnZwinck's great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43002154/6862601), look at these examples as well:

```
command='ls | wc -l'
eval $command
# outputs the correct result => 17
$command
ls: -l: No such file or directory
ls: wc: No such file or directory
ls: |: No such file or directory

command='ls -l $PWD'
eval $command
# outputs the contents of current directory
$command
# runs 'ls -l $PWD' literally as a command and ls tries to lookup $PWD as a file
ls: $PWD: No such file or directory
```

So, `eval` builtin interprets its arguments in the same way as shell would do.  However, in case of `$command`, shell expands the variable and literally treats the content as a command.

Comment: Note that `ls -l $PWD` works if you use `""` instead of `''` as I did in my question.

Comment: When you use `""`, the `PWD` variable is expanded at the time of assignment to `command`.  It's not expanded during the execution through `$command`.

Comment: Well, yeah, obviously. But I actually didn't think about the fact that `eval` eats up `''` and still expands the variables. So thanks.

Comment: `eval` doesn't "eat up" the single quotes; the shell removes them before `eval` is ever run.